# Return types for unimplemented methods in traits

Tags: scala, types, casting, type-inference, traits

Suppose I have a trait `SomeTrait` with an unimplemented method `func`. This method is going to return something that extends `SomeTrait`. In other words, I've got something like the following:

```
trait SomeTrait
{
  def func(x: Int): SomeTrait
}
```

Now, I implement a class `ExtensionClass` that extends `SomeTrait` and it turns out that I in fact want the implementation of `func` in this class to return an object of type `ExtensionClass`:

```
class ExtensionClass(val param: String) extends SomeTrait
{
  override def func(x: Int): SomeTrait = return new ExtensionClass("test")

  // ExtensionClass also defines another method not specified in SomeTrait
  def anotherMethod: String = return param ++ "!"
}
```

So far, everything above works nicely. The problem arises if I want to call `anotherMethod` on the object returned by `func` like so:

```
val extension = new ExtensionClass("hello")
extension.func(5).anotherMethod
```

The type system only recognises that the object given by `extension.func(5)` is of type `SomeTrait` and so `anotherMethod` is not visible. This brings us to my question:

**Question:**
Is it possible to make the above work without having to explicitly cast/pattern match on the result of `func`? For instance, can I update the type signature of `func` in `SomeTrait` so that some sort of type inference can happen? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a generic parameter:

```
trait SomeTrait[T <: SomeTrait[T]] {
    def func(x: Int): T
}

class ExtensionClass(val param: String) extends SomeTrait[ExtensionClass] {
    def func(x: Int) = new ExtensionClass("test")
    def anotherMethod: String = param ++ "!"
}
```

alternatively you could add an abstract type member:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    type T <: SomeTrait
    def func(x: Int): T
}

class ExtensionClass(val s: String) extends SomeTrait {
    type T = ExtensionClass
    def func(x: Int) = new ExtensionClass("test")
    def anotherMethod: String = s ++ "!"
}
```

Comment: It seems that `T` means different things on either side of `<:` in `T <: SomeTrait[T]`. Is this the case? If so, what exactly is going on?

Comment: @providence - No, T is the same on both sides e.g. `ExtensionClass` is a subtype of `SomeTrait[ExtensionClass]`. This is called the "recurring template pattern" and is a common approach to achieving this kind of static polymorphism in object hierarchies. See for example, `Enum` in Java.

Comment: And if I wanted to explicitly specify the return type of `func` in the implementation, what would I need to write? i.e in `def func(x: Int): ? = new ExtensionClass("test")` what replaces the ?

Comment: @providence - `func` returns a `T` and `T` is `ExtensionClass` in the example.